# Change Shortcode Value with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, shortcode

Is it possible to change `shortcode` PHP parameter value using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)?

`[jobs show_map="false"]` is the default value, and I want to set this value to `[jobs show_map="true"]` using javascript.

This is to enable `show mapview` and `hide mapview`; Say I'm trying to do a toggle mechanism between two below views of my website:

- [with map](http://pixelgrade.com/demos/listable/listings/)
- [without map](http://pixelgrade.com/demos/listable/listings-no-map)

Comment: have a listable theme installed in my site. I am looking to create show map hide map scenario. The following code makes the map hidden [jobs show_map="false"] and the following code shows map [jobs show_map="code"]... i would like to know whether is it possible to change the shortcode depending upon condition.... that is like when check box is checked it should show map and unchecked should hide map...

Comment: what i am trying to achieve is this.. pixelgrade.com/demos/listable/listings/… pixelgrade.com/demos/listable/listings-no-map Looking to introduce toggle button between these two layouts..... 
Toggle button Frontend to users... show map and hide map...[jobs show_map="false"] short code for map hidden view [jobs show_map="true"] short code for map view

Comment: I tried to express differently what you try to say... and added relevant tags. But you really must take your time to be clear. I know learning English takes time.